# Turning fast_executemany on is even slower than when it is off

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Using pyodbc, I wrote a Python program to extract data from Oracle and loads into SQL Server. The extraction from Oracle was instant, but there are some tables taking very long time to load, especially the tables with many columns (over 100+ columns) with a few of those columns at VARCHAR(4000) size (I am running pyodbc's executemany for the INSERT).

Turning fast_executemany = True seem to make the INSERT even slower. When turned off, loading a table of 40k rows took about 3minutes; and when turned on, loading the same amount of rows took about 15minutes.

Not sure if this means anything, but I did turned on SQL Profiler during each try and here is what I found: When it is turned off, the backend is doing a bunch of "sp_prepexec" and "sp_unprepare" for each inserts; and when it is turned on, the backend just did one time of "sp_prepare" and then a bunch of "sp_execute".

Any idea why the fast_executemany is not speeding up the INSERT, and in fact is even much longer?

Comment: You are probably better off configuring a linked server or doing a bulk insert via `bcp` etc

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to resolve my problem by limiting how many rows get inserted each time. I set my batch size for each INSERT operation to only 1000 rows at a time, and now the same INSERT operation of 40k rows took about 40secs, comparing to without setting a batch size of which took 15minutes.

I am guessing fast_executemany puts everything into memory before executing that INSERT, but if my column sizes are huge and if there are many rows to be inserted for each operation, it will put lot of burden on the memory and hence get much slower (?).